# iOS file upload - original filename

Tags: ios, iphone, html, file-upload, upload

I have a simple HTML file upload snippet that works under iOS as well. However my problem is that the filename of the uploaded file will always be 'image.jpeg'. Is there a way to get the original filename - i.e. 'IMG_0001.jpg' instead? The major issue is that if I have 2 files selected they both have the name of 'image.jpeg' as opposed to their unique names.

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: I'm using ng-file-upload. http://jsfiddle.net/danialfarid/s8kc7wg0/400/ (drop file)

Comment: You should by able to get the original filename from `$scope` and pass it to the server along with the request:  `$scope.filename = $scope.file.name;`

Answer (score 3):

Safari on iOS will always make the name of the uploaded file `image.jpeg`, presumably for security/privacy purposes. You need to generate your own name for the files, which is a good idea in general for uploaded files: you never want to trust the client too much.

If you are targeting more than just Safari on iOS, you will still need to handle this case because it is reasonable that people might upload multiple files with the same name, but originally located in different directories.

Comment: so I presume when you export the files to a computer these filenames get generated somehow as well? Or does the OS allow access to the 'original' filenames?

Comment: @Tamas iOS doesn't allow access to the original file name via `input[type=field]`. When exporting photos off an iOS device plugged into the computer, the computer has to first be trusted, then the computer can access the file names